# Communication between rails application and chrome app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nfc, google-chrome-app

Currently working on a rails application , i want to send and receive data to this chrome application https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-nfc.

I added  `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` function inside app.js file to send a simple "hello world" to my browser and

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response,sender,sendResponse){alert(response);});
```

to show it but I get nothing.
Is it the right way to communicate between them ?

Comment: See [external messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#external-webpage).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using near field (NFC)?  If not, you may want to do something much more simple to pass info between your Chrome App and Rails on server, use an XHR request:

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#external

Comment: Yes Im using NFC reader to extract data from an NFC tag , in this case is there any other solution ?